# Where does a question about a programming organization go?

Tags: discussion, scope

Let's say I wanted to ask a question that wasn't about a programming language, but the body behind it. For example, let's say I want to ask about how the [C++ WG21 committee](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/) receives defect reports.

Is that a question for Stack Overflow, Programmers.se, or neither?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, questions about an organization's policies and procedures should be directed at the organization itself.